# Error approving tag synonyms after swap

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Steps to reproduce:

1. Pick a tag and click "Synonyms"
2. Type a tag synonym and click the "Suggest" button
3. Click the "see all tag synonyms" link
4. Swap the tags on the unapproved suggested tag synonym
5. Click "Approve".

   - There should be an alert (Approve this synonym?) Instead, it goes to the error page. However, when I click back in the browser, it works correctly (pop up alert, click OK, synonym is approved.).

Also, the suggested synonym cannot be deleted until the page is refreshed.

It appears that the swap is made; I just can't approve it until the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just committed a fix for it, good catch